# How to validate email already exist or not in database using springboot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, validation

How to check, whether email exist or not in database using `springboot`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a 'help me code site'. You need to produce your attempt to the problem so far. Kindly go through this post for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe running a query like select from emails where your@email.to.ckeck and ensure the result is empty